# WiX: CopyFile leaves file orphaned on uninstall

Tags: wix, windows-installer, file-copying

I am copying an existing file as part of my WiX installer. The CopyFile tag works great however, when I uninstall the file I copied is left orphaned.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="CopyText" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Colin" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

    <Property Id="LICENSESIGPATH" Value="C:\projects\Setup\miCore2\Stuff\028 contents\License.txt.sig" ></Property>
        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="CopyText" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="CopyText" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" >
          <Component Id="License_sig" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Guid="*" KeyPath="yes">
            <CopyFile Id="License_sigCopy" DestinationProperty="INSTALLFOLDER"  DestinationName="License.txt.sig" SourceProperty="LICENSESIGPATH"   />
          </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

What is the best way to tell WiX to remove copied files on uninstall?

Comment: `<RemoveFile>` Click [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/removefile.html). I would put it in the same Component as the `<CopyFile>`

Comment: I can confirm that `<RemoveFile Id="License_sigRemove" Name="License.txt.sig" On="uninstall" />` works. I am surprised I need to do that.

Comment: Just as an explanations as to why you need to do this. When the windows installer uninstalls itself, it basically looks all the features, and components that were installed and the files linked to those features and components (eg files described in `<File>` tags). The `<CopyFile>` doesn't show up as a file installed by the installer (is not using a `<File>` tag), rather a separate action that happened as part of installing the License_sig component. Because of this, the installer doesn't associate that copied file as one it installed so it must also be removed via a secondary action.